# Product of trigonometric polynomials is a trigonometric polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometric-series

A trigonometric polynomial was defined as $$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_k \cos(kx) + b_k \sin(kx))$$

I heard somewhere that trigonometric polynomials have a ring structure, i.e. a product of two polynomials is again a polynomial.

I was wondering how can one see it. A direct attempt to multiply two polynomials seem to result in a mess.

---

**Edit**:

Using a suggestion from nicomezi from below I go to the complex representation:

$$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{n}(e^{ikx}z_k + e^{-ikx} \bar z_k )$$

We can also "hide" the first term:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{n}(e^{ikx}z_k + e^{-ikx} \bar z_k ), z_0 = a_0$$

Now when we multiply two polynomials of degrees $n$ and $m$ we get a sum of terms of the form:

$$\frac{1}{4}(e^{ikx}z_k + e^{-ikx} \bar z_k )(e^{ilx}z_l + e^{-ilx} \bar z_l )= \frac{1}{4}(e^{i(k+l)x}z_kz_l + e^{-i(k+l)x}\overline{z_k z_l}) + \frac{1}{4}(e^{i(k-l)x}z_k\bar z_l + e^{-i(k-l)x} \overline{z_k \bar z_l}), 1 \le k \le n, 1 \le l \le m$$

So each term is a polynomial of degree $(k+l)$, thus the whole product is a polynomial of degree $(n+m)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to multiply two polynomials, that does, indeed, result in a mess.  Instead, all you need to show is that:

- $\cos(kx)\cos(lx)$ is a trigonometric polynomial,
- $\cos(kx)\sin(lx)$ is a trigonometric polynomial, and
- $\sin(kx)\sin(lx)$ is a trigonometric polynomial.

The rest comes from linearity.

Let's check $\cos(kx)\sin(lx)$ is a trigonometric polynomial; the rest of the cases are very similar.

Since $e^{ikx}=\cos(kx)+i\sin(kx)$, $\cos(kx)=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}\right)$.  Similarly, $\sin(lx)=\frac{1}{2}\left(ie^{-ilx}-ie^{ilx}\right)$.  Therefore, 
$$\cos(kx)\sin(lk)=\frac{1}{4}\left(ie^{i(k-l)x}+ie^{-i(k+l)x}-ie^{i(k+l)x}-ie^{i(l-k)x}\right).$$
Since our answer should be real, we are only interested in the real part of this, which is:
$$
\cos(kx)\sin(lx)=-\frac{1}{2}\sin((k-l)x)+\frac{1}{2}\sin((k+l)x)
$$

Answer (score 2):

I believe the neatest way to see this is through the Fourier transform.

You can think of the series that you have denoted as a collection of frequencies that you are in possession of. Multiplying the two series in the time domain is equivalent to [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) in the frequency domain.

If you are not aware of what convolution is, it is in some sense a rule of combining two functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f$ is "smeared" according to $g$'s pattern.

Comment: thanks for your effort, I must admit that I am at the very beginning of my studies of Fourier series and Fourier transform is something above my level yet. But if I believe my class instructor I should be able to find an answer to this question "at my level of knowledge".

Comment: Another way but less elegant is to consider the reals trigonometric polynomials as a particular case of complex trigonometric polynomials, which are easier to manipulate. Then you may be able to prove it quite easily with mathematical induction.